# Splitting strings into substrings and getting an indicator in each their own column within a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have already asked this question once. It was marked as "an exact replica" of another question, but it can't have been, because the answer to that other question doesn't work in my case!

I have a dataframe that is the response dataset from a Google Forms questionnaire survey. Google Forms have put the answers to multiple choice, multiple answers questions into one variable, so that it looks something like this:

```
Q1   Q2        Q3
1   "A, B ,C"  S 
2   "C, D"     T
1   "A, C, E"  U
3   "D"        V
2   "B, E"     Z
```

The actual A, B, C, D and E values are longer statements with commas in them, such as

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
Veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
```

Google Forms have reported them with commas between them, but I can change those commas into any other character by hand if I need to (since I know which commas are within statements and which are between, so to say).

I want to get my data to look something like this:

```
Q1  Q2        Q2A Q2B Q2C Q2D Q2E   Q3
1   "A, B, C"  1   1   1   0   0     S
2   "C, D"     0   0   1   1   0     T
1   "A, C, E"  1   0   1   0   1     U
3   "D"        0   0   0   1   0     V
2   "B, E"     0   1   0   0   1     Z
```

In the question that was supposedly exactly the same as mine but wasn't, the answer was to use a package called "splitstackshape" and a function called cSplit_e. When I do that, I get an error message saying:

```
test21 <- cSplit_e(test2, split.col= "X1a", sep = "!")

Error in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec)) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(listOfValues, as.integer) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: ....
...
n: In lapply(listOfValues, as.integer) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Q2, "\\s*,\\s*"))
names(d1) <- paste0(names(df1)[2], names(d1))
cbind(df1[1:2], d1, df1[3])
#  Q1      Q2 Q2A Q2B Q2C Q2D Q2E Q3
#1  1 A, B ,C   1   1   1   0   0  S
#2  2    C, D   0   0   1   1   0  T
#3  1 A, C, E   1   0   1   0   1  U
#4  3       D   0   0   0   1   0  V
#5  2    B, E   0   1   0   0   1  Z
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Q1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), Q2 = c("A, B ,C", 
"C, D", "A, C, E", "D", "B, E"), Q3 = c("S", "T", "U", "V", "Z"
)), .Names = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```